# Branding menu missing in SSRS 2017

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2017

Considering how to implement branding in our SSRS, but the branding menu is missing from my menu.

[image]

I distinctly remember when I first installed SSRS, that it was available, but soon afterwards it disappeared.

My user has administrator access.

Currently have Version 14.0.600.594 (October 2017) installed.

Below is a screenshot from Microsoft's website.
[image]

Comment: Branding is only available in  Enterprise edition, what version are you running?

Comment: Ok, that makes sense then - we run standard.